# PHPUnit CI Test against different vendor versions

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, continuous-integration, phpunit

I'm writing PHP Software with composer and PHPUnit CI. 
I set it up to test against different PHP versions - php 5.6 / 7.0 / 7.1.

But my software have 3rd party software dependencies.
How can I setup unit test to run against different vendor modules ?

For example: My software wants symfony/forms either ~2.8 either ~3.0.

How do I setup 2 tests: one with symfony 2.8 and one with 3.0 ?

I think the only way is with some kind of before_script: composer require vendor:~specific_version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple `composer.json`, for example :

- `composer.5_6.json` (with `"require": {"php":">=5.6", "symfony/symfony":"~2.8"}`)
- `composer.7_0.json` (with `"require": {"php":">=7.0", "symfony/symfony":"~3.0"}`)

and then in your `before_script` :

- `cp composer.5_6.json composer.json && composer update`
- run your 5.6 unit tests
- `rm composer.json && rm composer.lock`
- `cp composer.7_0.json composer.json && composer update`
- run your 7.0 unit tests

Comment: Yeah, that seems easy enough. But that way you can bloat repository with a lot of composer files.

I found this for Travis-CI after searching a while: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Testing-Against-Multiple-Versions-of-Dependencies

Comment: yes if you want to use an external CI system, this is another question ! I use gitlab CI to try different version https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/php.html#test-against-different-php-versions-in-docker-builds, I think it should be the same with Travis. You can also git ignore composer.*.json. You can also set composer vendor-dir to vendor5_6 and vendor7_0